# Pass checkbox values to colorbox overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a series of check boxes on a page and I want to pass the values of all the boxes which are selected across to an colorbox overlay / secondary page.

In this case I want the colourbox to open an iframe so a way of adding the values to a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above only works for a single check box for multiple check boxes with the colour box overlay use

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="colorboxsend">
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

     $("a#colorboxsend").click(function () {

         var allVals = [];
         $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 allVals.push($(this).val());
             };

             var url = "http://localhost:60980/mypages.aspx?pv=" + allVals;
             $(this).attr("href", url);

             $("a#colorboxsend").colorbox({ href: url });
         });

     });
 });
```

This will produce an array like ?values=val1,val2,val3

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "http://example.com?value=" + $('input[checkbox]').val();
```

Or

```
var url = "http://example.com?checked=" + $('input[checkbox]').attr("checked");
```

Comment: @TheAlbear; better brush up on your understanding of Jquery selectors. The code supplied by @Andreas AL will select all input elements of type checkbox on the page - so YES it will work for multiple check boxes.

Comment: I did test this and it was only ever returning the last check box value in the array. which is why I implemented the method below.

Comment: :) Super. Hope you found your answer